# Are there any operator in Haskell that fold list of actions with (>>)?

Tags: haskell, monads

I want some operator `<?>` that could transform this

```
test arg1 >>
test arg2 >>
test arg3 >>
test arg4
```

to this

```
test <?> [ arg1
         , arg2
         , arg3
         , arg4
         ]
```

Comment: For future reference, you can find functions *by type* with [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+b%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+m+%28%29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use [**`mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mapM-95-) for that:

```
mapM_ test [arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4]
```

Or if you really want to write it infix:

```
test `mapM_` [ arg1
             , arg2
             , arg3
             , arg4
             ]
```